# ERROR Could not run the 'getMediaStream' pipeline for 'x' when loading images

Tags: pipelines, media-library

I have an issue where our custom pipeline which crops images is not running correctly for some images. It was working fine and still seems to work correctly for the existing images but for new images it no longer works correctly.

These are the parameters we are sending to fire our pipeline:

> /-/media/test-image.jpg?mw=660&mh=530&as=1&centercrop=1

It is not cropping new images anymore and if I look at the error in the logs this seems to be falling back to the out of the box image pipeline:

> 14028 16:47:19 ERROR Could not run the 'getMediaStream' pipeline for
>   '/sitecore/media library/test-image'. Original media data will be
>   used. Exception: System.ArgumentException Message: Parameter is not
>   valid. Source: System.Drawing    at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream
>   stream)    at
>   Sitecore.Resources.Media.SaveColorProfileProcessor.Process(GetMediaStreamPipelineArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Resources.Media.Media.GetStreamFromPipeline(MediaOptions
>   options, Boolean& canBeCached)

I've looked into it and thought it might be this bug, but it's for an older version of Sitecore:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/856744

More info here:

https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2015/11/21/could-not-run-the-getmediastream-pipeline/

I've also checked the permissions on the images and they seem fine and this issue seems to affect all image types, jpeg, gif, pn etc so I'm a bit stumped what might be causing it.

**Other details:** We are Running Sitecore 8.1 - update 2.

**--Update--**

I've taken a copy of the SaveColorProfileProcessor Pipeline and it is indeed throwing an error when trying to read the properties of the image. I've wrapped it in a try{}catch{} and this is skips over the error and proceeds as expected with other Pipelines and resizes the images correctly. I have opened a ticket with Sitecore Support regarding this and why GetMediaStream() is returning this error:

> 'mediaStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'

I'll update here further once I know more.

```
            try
            {
                PropertyItem propertyItem =
                    ((IEnumerable<PropertyItem>) new Bitmap(mediaStream).PropertyItems)
                        .SingleOrDefault<PropertyItem>((Func<PropertyItem, bool>) (x => x.Id == 34675));
                if (propertyItem == null)
                    return;
                args.CustomData.Add("ColorProfile", (object) propertyItem);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Error saving colour profile: " + ex.Message, ex);
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Do you have Dianoga (Image Compression) installed on your instance?

Comment: No I don't believe so Richard - I did read this post about that too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952875/sitecore-getmediastream-is-not-working.

Comment: Looks like you have some custom parameters there `as=1&centercrop=1` - have you tried without those?

Comment: Yeah those are required by our pipeline to do the center crop. However If I remove these then I still get the same error in the logs. Oddly if I save down one of the old images where this does work still and re-upload it then I get the same problem so I don't think it's the image or pipleline that is the problem but something else effecting new images, perhaps during upload?

Comment: So it sounds like even the out of the box Pipeline is failing too as this works on old images but not new ones:

/-/media/test-image.jpeg?mw=400&mh=250

Comment: Could you try flipping your app-pool and deleting everything in /App_Data/MediaCache? - edit: Will not fix the issue, but will provide a further clue as to where to look

Comment: I've done this Mark. I get the same result. Interestingly if I then look in the mediacache folder the old images that work show up in the folder but if I look at the new ones they are 0 bytes.

Comment: Do the new images get a thumbnail generated in the CMS? Also can you see the image in the Attachment field when you look at a new media item?

Comment: Yeah the image shows fine in the media library and the thumbnail preview in the component is fine. It also seems to have the same properties saved on the old image as the new one. If I save an old image (that works) from my browser and re-upload it to Sitecore with a new name though it doesn't work...very odd.

Comment: @aseabridge can you check with ShowConfig, that your <mediaTypes> configuration has not been corrupted for some reason?

Comment: I've checked the <mediaTypes> configuration and it seems ok to me.

Answer (score 5):

That processor; the `Sitecore.Resources.Media.SaveColorProfileProcessor` seems bugged to me. I know that's not entirely constructive, but I'll exemplify why I believe this to be.

Your query string contains resizing information. This processor is then tasked with grabbing the color profile for use in resizing later on. In doing this, it opens up a `Stream`.

[image]

Which takes you here:

[image]

And ultimately here.

[image]

Now here's the thing. From what I can tell; if your media item isn't in the MediaCache at this point; this method will **run the `<getMediaStream>`** pipeline **again** to get the stream.

And I'm guessing this blows up, as you probably cannot open the `Stream` twice or some such.

Comment: That's where I'd go to also - seems to be able to get in an endless loop

Comment: The error seems to be because its returning a null from that `args.MediaData.MediaItem.GetMediaStream` and then passing that into the `Bitmap` constructor - it does look like a weird bit of code!

Comment: That could be of course. Possible if this code returns null.

      Sitecore.Resources.Media.Media media = MediaManager.GetMedia(new MediaUri(this.InnerItem));
      if (media == null)
        return (Stream) null;

Comment: Thanks for this info. This does indeed seem to be the culptit. I've updated my question above to explain what I've done so far to work around this.

Comment: I found some discussions on this on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571022/how-to-find-reason-for-generic-gdi-error-when-saving-an-image - it could be related. Generally; perhaps meta data on your images is incompatible with the default GDI library.

Answer (score 3):

Coming back to this after implementing a solution. In the end I had to write a custom pipeline to replace the out of the box one and wrap the call to GetMediaStream as suggested by Mark & Rich.

I'm still waiting for Sitecore support to come back to me on this and let me know if there is a better solution.

Here is the code in case anyone else needs to do this:

```
public class CustomSaveColorProfileProcessor
{
    public void Process(GetMediaStreamPipelineArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");

        var imageIsInvalidForProcessing = !args.MediaData.MimeType.StartsWith("image/", StringComparison.Ordinal) 
                 || !args.Options.GetTransformationOptions().ContainsResizing() 
                 || MediaManager.Config.GetImageFormat(args.MediaData.Extension, (ImageFormat)null) == null;

        if (imageIsInvalidForProcessing) return;

        using (Stream mediaStream = args.MediaData.MediaItem.GetMediaStream())
        {
            try
            {
                PropertyItem propertyItem =
                    ((IEnumerable<PropertyItem>) new Bitmap(mediaStream).PropertyItems)
                        .SingleOrDefault<PropertyItem>((Func<PropertyItem, bool>) (x => x.Id == 34675));
                if (propertyItem == null)
                    return;
                args.CustomData.Add("ColorProfile", (object) propertyItem);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Error saving colour profile: " + ex.Message, ex);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then patched it in-place of the out of the box one like so:

```
<getMediaStream>
            <processor type="Custom.Sitecore.Extensions.Pipelines.CustomSaveColorProfileProcessor, Custom.Sitecore.Extensions"
                                         patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Resources.Media.SaveColorProfileProcessor, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
</getMediaStream>
```

Comment: Hey, did you get a fix for this issue from the Sitecore Support?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't @PascalMathys as they couldn't replicate this on an out the box install unfortunately. I'm not sure what is causing it but this seems to resolve the problem.

Comment: FYI looks like this fix is in Sitecore.Kernel since Sitecore 9 (maybe 8.2.5+ too although its a bit different)

Comment: @AdamSeabridge - Was the cropping done as part of the CropProcessor in AdvanceImage Module. I am getting the same issue , but resulting in SQL Connection Pool Issue

Message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.